# Status code GeneralFailure in SmtpClient exception C#

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I am sending mail using SmtpClient.I got an innerexception with staus code : GeneralFailure.When is looked into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpstatuscode(v=vs.90) it says "The transaction could not occur. You receive this error when the specified SMTP host cannot be found".Is the exception due to network issue?or something else?

Answer (score 1):

"You receive this error when the specified SMTP host cannot be found"

Do you have terminal access to the machine where this code is running?  If you "ping {mailserver}", does it resolve the correct IP and return responses?  Note that ping might not work across routers/Internet, as many people filter/block ICMP now.  Step one would be confirming that the IP can be resolved and that it's correct.  If ping doesn't work because it's blocked, try "telnet {mailserver} 25", which will connect you to the SMTP port on the mail server.  If it connects, then that's not the problem.

Comment: See i am getting this exception when trying to send more than 3 mails at a time.At that time 1 or 2 fails and others sent successfully.when i resend the failed ones they will send successfully.